# Scipy SLSQP method gives wrong solution

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, nonlinear-optimization

I just started to learn scipy optimization, with SLSQP method. Tried to solve a simple problem. But the algorithm does not give global minimum in constraied region or gives point that is not feasible.
Here is code using optimization algorithm:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds

def simpleFunction(x):
    x1 = float(x[0])
    x2 = float(x[1])
    return x2*(x1-x2)

def g1(x):
    x1 = float(x[0])
    x2 = float(x[1])
    return (x1-5)**2 - x2



def g2(x):
    x1 = float(x[0])
    x2 = float(x[1])
    return (x2+x1) - 10

def g3(x):
    x1 = float(x[0])
    x2 = float(x[1])
    return x2-0.8*x1



g1_ineq = {'type': 'ineq', 
                   'fun' :g1
                   }

g2_ineq = {'type': 'ineq', 
                   'fun' :g2
                   }

g3_ineq = {'type': 'ineq', 
                   'fun' :g3
                   }

x0 = np.array([5 ,8])
bnds = Bounds([5, 3], [10, 10])
cons = ([g1_ineq, g2_ineq, g3_ineq])
res = minimize(simpleFunction, x0, method='SLSQP',  #
                constraints= cons, #
                options={'disp': True}, #
               bounds=bnds)
print(res.x)
print(simpleFunction(res.x))
print(simpleFunction([5, 4]))
print(res.x)
print(simpleFunction(res.x))
print(simpleFunction([5, 4])) #the true minimum point

#Some results depemnding on the initial point (initial guess -> algorithm output -> function value)
#[0, 0] -> [5. 3.] -> 6.0
#[5, 4] -> [5, 4] -> 4.0
#[5, 5] -> [ 8.16230102 10.] -> -18.376
#[6, 6] -> [ 8.16230102 10.] -> -18.376
#[10, 10] -> [ 8.16230102 10.] -> -18.376
#[5 ,8] -> [ 8.16230102 10.] -> -18.376
```

And this is code for graphical solution of the problem. Infeasible regions are painted blue, cost function isolines are dashed:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
from typing import List, Set, Dict, Tuple



def simpleFunction(x1, x2):

    return x2*(x1-x2)

def g1(x1, x2):
    return (x1-5)**2 - x2

def g2(x1, x2):
    return -x1 +5

def g3(x1, x2):
    return x2-0.8*x1

def g4(x1, x2):
    return -x2 +3

def g5(x1, x2):
    return (x2+x1) - 10

Z1 = 0

functions = [
    (lambda x1, x2: g1(x1,x2), Z1,'g1'), (lambda x1, x2: g2(x1,x2), Z1,'g2'), (lambda x1, x2: g3(x1,x2), Z1,'g3') , 
    (lambda x1, x2: g4(x1,x2), Z1,'g1'), (lambda x1, x2: g3(x1,x2), Z1,'g1'),]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 10, 1000), np.linspace(0, 10, 1000))

for f, z,name in functions:
    plt.contour(X, Y, f(X, Y), levels = [0], colors='black')
    plt.contourf(X, Y, f(X, Y), [0, 1000], colors='blue', alpha=0.1)


plt.contour(X, Y, simpleFunction(X, Y), levels=100, linestyles='dashed', colors='black')
plt.title('feasible region')
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.xlabel('x1')
plt.ylabel('x2')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried to disable some constraints, to change bounds but nothing helped. It gives proper solution only from initial guess point that equals to real minimum point - [5, 4] (with "Positive directional derivative for linesearch    (Exit mode 8)"). From [0,0] it gives feasible value, but not minimum, from others it gives infeasible values that doesn't meet constraints

Comment: `minimize` interprets inequality constraints as being `>= 0`. You are interpreting them as being `<= 0`. Just multiply your constraints by -1.

Comment: Check the value of `res.success` and `res.message`.

Comment: "*But the algorithm does not give global minimum in constraied region or gives point*" I guess it's worth mentioning that SLSQP (like most algorithms) tries to find a local minimizer, not a global one. Hence, if you're problem is not convex, you have no guarantee that the found optimizer is a global one.